# emergency-mode repair failed, nothing to do?

Tags: sql-server-2005, dbcc

A production server got I/O disk error's I tried to fix it with dbcc but it got unexpected errors and crashed after a few minutes. so I took the file down and copied it over to a new machine.

I have no recent backup available fast, (its a online backup that takes very long to download).

```
File activation failure. The physical file name "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\mydb_log.LDF" may be incorrect.
The log cannot be rebuilt because the database was not cleanly shut down.
DBCC results for 'mydb'.

Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 1
SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid (expected 1:3724880; actual 0:0). It occurred during a read of page (1:3724880) in database ID 5 at offset 0x0000071aca0000 in file '\mydb.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

The emergency-mode repair failed.You must restore from backup.
```

Comment: what was the DBCC command that you ran?

Comment: DBCC CHECKDB ('mydb', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS);

Comment: outside of scripting out objects and data ("generate scripts" from ssms) to recreate the db, it seems like you're going to have to wait for that backup to download. hopefully it's not corrupt.

Comment: what is the scripting option.. I need the data from the backup till now. (the last good backup was last week).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429902/generate-script-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: I have no access to the database... to generate scripts. the database is not opening up.

Comment: @Ezi You need to wait for the backup.  There's no really another option.

Comment: Do you not have the required permissions to restore the database?

Comment: @JNK I'm downloading the backup now. but I'm concerned about the data from the last few days. is there a way to get out a bit of data from that mess?

Comment: @Ezi What's your recovery model?  If it's SIMPLE then you don't have any other options are are going to suffer a bit because of your inadequate backup model.  If it's FULL then you may be able to get some data from the log.

Comment: Yes its simple. but let me make sure one thing.. the file is 60GB big (with a lot of empty space, data is only 26GB), maybe this IO garbage is in the empty space or in a table I don't need. can I cut off the problem pages and get out the valid data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - as many of you replied in the comment's - that there is no way around a backup is the only way to go. and I did find a good backup and it was restored. that you all for the help.